# React NextJS 13 page navigation - react-relay query on page - prerendering error during build

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js13, react-relay

I have a react component called `pages\productDetail.tsx` which loads a product detail data. The `productId` comes from query parameter, the data comes from a graphQL query called `productStateByKeyQuery` and is defined in an external file. Starting the `npm run dev` the page works, when I navigate to this page an url like this: `` the data is loaded and the detail page looks good.

When I start `npm run build` on my machine, the build fails with error:

> Error occurred prerendering page "/productDetail". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> RelayNetwork: No data returned for operation `productStateByKeyQuery`, got error(s):
> Variable `id` is required.

This seems correct, during build there is no `productId` available. But how to tell nexjs not to prerender this page (or the part of this page) because the graphQL query won't work during build time?

My code is:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react'
import { useLazyLoadQuery } from "react-relay";

import {productStateByKeyQuery} from '@/queries/productStateByKey'
import type {productStateByKeyQuery as qt} from '@/queries/__generated__/productStateByKeyQuery.graphql'


export default function ProductDetail() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const productId = router.query["productId"];
    const data = useLazyLoadQuery<qt>(productStateByKeyQuery, {"id": productId}, {fetchPolicy: 'store-or-network'} );

  return (
    <>
        <div>ProductDetail {router.query["productId"]}</div>
        <div>ID:         {data.productStateByKey?.id}    </div>
        <div>Version:         {data.productStateByKey?.version}    </div>
        <div>Product code:         {data.productStateByKey?.product?.code}    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Where the query definitions is something like this:

```
import { graphql } from 'relay-runtime';

export const productStateByKeyQuery = graphql`query productStateByKeyQuery($id: UUID!) {
  productStateByKey(id: $id) {
    id
    product { code }
  }
}`;
```

Don't sure about to move this code to `getServerSideProps` because of using the route query parameter - but I am not too familiar with these concepts. Any advice will be welcome!